Why did Bugs show Neo her tattoo?
Before convincing Neo to follow her about the truth in The Matrix Resurrections (2021), Bugs shows him the
rabbit tattoo on her shoulder, and then they both proceed to the portal
door to Tokyo.

Why did Bugs show Neo her tattoo?

I've never met anyone with tattoos that doesn't take every possible opportunity, no matter how tenuous, to show them to people.

I've not seen the new film, but that sounds like a pretty direct callback to the "follow the white rabbit" setup in the original.
